# What is the meaning of "that" as an Internet slang?

Tags: internet, interjections, comprehension

I see many times in comment sections of Internet forums such comments as the following:

> A: This girl is so ugly and I know nobody will date her ever.
>
> B: That!

What does it mean?

Comment: I think it's an affirmative.  That is, it expresses agreement.  It's like saying "That's the truth!"

Comment: "you said it man" , "amen brother", "spot on", "absolutely"

Comment: It is also a type of interjection that even our more elite, intellectual friends might make saying "indubitably" : )

Comment: FWIW Urban dictionary confirms all these suspicions.  "A response in agreement or in support of something just said. Agreeing with someone." *-- This movie sucks! -- That!*

Comment: @Tom22 - Could you make that an answer?

Comment: @aparente001 sure, done

Comment: There's no such thing as "a" slang. Slang is a mass noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"That!" is an affirmation** by the person saying it approving of what another speaker has just said.

Here are some similar ways of saying the same thing with perhaps different flavors from different parts of the US(or GB for 'spot on')

"you said it man" , "amen brother", "spot on", "absolutely"

It is also a type of interjection that even our more elite, intellectual friends might make saying "indubitably" : )